# PANDAS. Grouping dataframe items and stack plot

Tags: pandas, group-by

I have  a pandas dataframe as below.

[image]

I want to be able to plot the barchart with the same Names on the same stacked bar and colored differently
like this:

[image]

Thanks for any help
Jason

Answer (score 1):

Not totally colored as you want, but you can use this as a start:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['R1','T1','Y1','R1','T2','T1'],
                  'volume':[10,15,12,12,5,2]})

(df.assign(c=df.groupby('Name').cumcount())
  .pivot(index='Name', columns='c',values='volume')
  .plot.bar(stacked=True)
)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thankyou, I have been searching and was trying the below, why wouldn't this approach work?                                                                                                      
 df2= df.groupby(['Name'])['Volume'].sum().unstack()
 df2.plot(kind='bar',stacked=True)